# Lookup cell value from a list then write result to a correct column

Tags: python

I have a product list which contains around 9,000 products as well as this I have ~60 product groups. Each product is member of one or multiple product group and some of them doesn't have any group membership.

If I run following code,

```
PRODUCTGROUPS = {'PRODUCTGROUP-A': ['product1', 'product3'], 'PRODUCTGROUP-B': ['product3'], 'PRODUCTGROUP-C': []}

HEADER = ['Products'] + [*PRODUCTGROUPS]

with open('products.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    groupwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    groupwriter.writerow(HEADER)

    for product in products:
        print(product)
        groupwriter.writerow([product])
```

It gives me following csv file. (`PRODUCTGROUPS` is a nested dictionary which contains groups and its members(products).)

```
Products       | PRODUCTGROUP-A | PRODUCTGROUP-B | PRODUCTGROUP-C
product1
product2
product3
```

I would like to lookup product name in `PRODUCTGROUPS`, if it exist in a product group I should mark the corresponding cell. Something like this,

```
Products       | PRODUCTGROUP-A | PRODUCTGROUP-B | PRODUCTGROUP-C
product1       |      X         |                |
product2       |                |                |
product3       |      X         |        X       |
```

I can use list comprehensions to check group memberships but I couldn't find a way to mark the corresponding cell.

Comment: Can you make a minimal example with, say 5 products and 3 groups?

Comment: I think example above is minimal enough, just 3 products and 3 groups?

Comment: You need to show the contents of a sample `PRODUCTGROUPS` that would theorically produce the final output you desire.

Comment: You need to add some theoretical data or sample data you are working with, so we can help you get your desired output.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question and added a sample `PRODUCTGROUPS`